# Comparing and replacing column items pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, lambda, where-clause, apply, string-comparison

I have three columns C1,C2,C3 in panda dataframe. My aim is to replace C1_i by C2_j whenever C3_i=C1_j. These are all strings. I was trying where but failed. What is a good way to do this avoiding for loop?

If my data frame is

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c2': ['d','e','f'], 'c3': ['c', 'z', 'b']})
```

Then I want c3 to be replaced by ['f','z','e']

I tried this, which takes very long time.

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    for j in range(0,len(df)):
        if (df.iloc[i]['c1']==df.iloc[j]['c3']):
            df.iloc[j]['c3']=accounts.iloc[i]['c2']
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df['c3'] = df['c3'].map(df.set_index('c1')['c2']).fillna(df['c3'])
```

Alternative solution with [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html):

```
df['c3'].update(df['c3'].map(df.set_index('c1')['c2']))

print (df)
  c1 c2 c3
0  a  d  f
1  b  e  z
2  c  f  e
```

Answer (score 0):

Example data:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'a':['10','4','3','40','5'], 'b':['5','4','3','2','1'], 'c':['s','d','f','g','h']})
```

Output:

```
    a  b  c
0  10  5  s
1   4  4  d
2   3  3  f
3  40  2  g
4   5  1  h
```

Code:

```
def replace(df):
    if len(dataframe[dataframe.b==df.a]) != 0:
        df['a'] = dataframe[dataframe.b==df.a].c.values[0] 
    return df

dataframe = dataframe.apply(replace, 1)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  5  0
1  2  4  0
2  0  3  0
3  4  2  0
4  5  1  0
```

Is it what you want?